# Backup And Restore iPhone Text Messages

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, messages

I have an iPhone that I need to wipe because I need to send it to Apple for the [Lock Button Replacement Program](https://www.apple.com/support/iphone5-sleepwakebutton/).

The only issue is I need to restore my iPhone and I don't want to lose my text messages and iMessages. If I backup my iPhone to iTunes will I be able to recover them when I get my iPhone back and still use them with the 'messages' application and not a 'SQL lite' app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An iTunes backup includes text messages. [See this Apple page for what is included.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204269) Notice that to restore everything, including passwords, you need to encrypt the iTunes backup with a password.